# Unable to mount btrfs volume

Tags: linux, centos, mount, btrfs

Recently my file server stops working (Centos 7.7).
The btrfs vol "clouddata" unable to mount. The server hangs during mounting it in read-write mode.
I thought space exhausted on it:

```
    [root@cloud auto]# btrfs fi show
    Label: 'clouddata'  uuid: 90224df7-9d85-48f7-8cb5-a6689fc4f0a5
    Total devices 1 FS bytes used 12.42TiB
    devid    1 size 14.45TiB used 12.84TiB path /dev/sda5
```

14.45 TB disk is hardware RAID10 on DELL R740xd. All drives are OK.

Mount options:

```
    /dev/sda5 /data01 btrfs compress=lzo,discard,clear_cache,subvol=data01   0 2
```

I can mount it in read-only.
Other partitions using ext4 file system.
Btrfs was chosen for "clouddata" because of snapshots .
Server log-files:

```
    [  169.678015] BTRFS: error (device sda5) in maybe_insert_hole:4859: errno=-17 Object already exists
    [  169.678102] BTRFS info (device sda5): forced readonly
    [  169.678168] BTRFS warning (device sda5): Skipping commit of aborted transaction.
    [  169.678178] BTRFS: error (device sda5) in cleanup_transaction:1851: errno=-17 Object already exists

    [root@cloud cifs]# btrfs --version
    btrfs-progs v4.9.1
```

The command "btrfs check --repair /dev/sda5" failed with:

```
    Feb  2 22:58:09 cloud kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 2321 (btrfs) score 946 or sacrifice child
    Feb  2 22:58:09 cloud kernel: Killed process 2321 (btrfs), UID 0, total-vm:23160652kB, anon-rss:15259688kB, file-rss:176kB, shmem-rss:0kB
```

Is it free space problem? How to delete all snapshots on unmounted volume?
There were no power outage.

Answer (score 0):

Zero-log resolved this situation. However btrfs-wiki not recommend using it.
I'm switching back to zfs on FreeBSD.